# Erro ao usar a função prepare() do PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tô em um novo projeto, e preciso usar o `prepare()` do PDO, não sei porque, mas só com ele que tá dando esse erro, toda vez que tem alguma função, ou alguma linha com `prepare()`, o PHP retorna um erro.

Já procurei na SO inteira, achei respostas, mas tentei todas e nenhuma pergunta era igual a minha/ou era parecida, mas a resposta não resolvia.

Código da página `conexao.php`:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=central", "root", "");
```

Código da página `index.php`:

```
require_once('conexao.php');
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO logs VALUES (:id, :type, :info)");
$sql->execute(array(":id" => NULL, ":type" => $type, ":info" => $info));
```

Erro informado:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2
```

Comment: Gustavo tem de nos dar mais informação, é só esse erro que dá? Verifique se em `conexao.php` está definida a `$pdo` com `var_dump($pdo);` a seguir a criar o PDO.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido essa semana, o sistema funcionava normalmente em um server, após desinstalar o xampp e reinstalar em outra maquina o sistema apresentava o erro. Passei pra fazer a conexão no mesmo arquivo index e solucionou. Não procurei onde estava o erro porque não tive tempo ainda.

Comment: `$pdo` parece não existir no arquivo conexão.php ou está faltando o include/require no index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria bom se postasses o código todo para melhor esclarecimentos. Seja como for, tente aprimorar o código para a conexão.

```
<?php
if(!defined("HOST")){ define('HOST','localhost'); }
if(!defined("DATABASE")){ define('DATABASE','central');}
if(!defined("USER")){ define('USER','root'); }
if(!defined("PASS")){ define('PASS',''); }

$conexao = 'mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE;

try{
    $pdo = new PDO($conexao, USER, PASS);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOexception $e){
    echo "Erro ao conectar" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado. Um abraço